# javascript multiple rating svg star click

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a rating star animation, on click should make the parent(span) active with a class.
I have multiple rating and I have the star 1 to 5 rating with also the half rating should work.

Currently I can increase. **But I can't go from say 4 back to 1**

**Please** have a look at my demo for a "fully" working example

This is a js css challenge:-)

**JS**

```
var ratingElemOne = $('.ratingOne input[name="starOne"]');
 
ratingElemOne.change(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
 

var ratingElemTwo = $('.ratingTwo input[name="starTwo"]');

ratingElemTwo.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-8 md-col-8 pt2 relative">
  <svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="starOne" viewBox="0 0 28 28" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
      <title>Star Rating</title>
      <path class="starOne" d="M13.996,22.501 L22.649,27.997 L20.352,17.637 L27.996,10.667 L17.930,9.768 L13.996,-0.003 L10.063,9.768 L-0.003,10.667 L7.641,17.637 L5.345,27.997 L13.996,22.501 Z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>

  <p>Value for money?</p>
  <div class="rating ratingOne">
    <fieldset class="rating-fieldset">
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="starOne5" class="rating-checkbox" value="5" name="starOne" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star4half" class="rating-checkbox" value="4.5" name="starOne" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars" name="star">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star4" class="rating-checkbox" value="4" name="starOne" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star3half" class="rating-checkbox" value="3.5" name="starOne" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star3" class="rating-checkbox" value="3" name="starOne" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars" name="star">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star2half" class="rating-checkbox" value="2.5" name="starOne" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star2" class="rating-checkbox" value="2" name="starOne" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star1half" class="rating-checkbox" value="1.5" name="starOne" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="star1" class="rating-checkbox" value="1" name="starOne" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="starhalf" class="rating-checkbox" value="0.5" name="starOne" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars">
          <svg role="img" aria-label="rating">
            <use xlink:href="#starOne"></use>
          </svg>
        </label>
      </span>
      <small>Rate Now</small>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/mq2xfp9L/

Answer (score 0):

It is way easier if you create all SVG client-side, using a Custom Element (supported in all modern Browsers):

- copied **only the d-path** from a star icon
- Edited the d-path in https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to a **100x100**
  viewBox/grid
- made it an **inverse** star by prepending `M0 0h100v100h-100v-100` to the path
- Created a new SVG file in a `0 0 N 100` viewBox to fit all stars.. see below
- Added a **background rectangle** setting **gold** color rating
- Used  inverse stars, each at an x-offset
- added **rectangles** ***covering*** all half-stars
- set inline events `onclick` and `onmouseover` on every "half-star"

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.5"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
<star-rating stars=7 rating="50%"
             bgcolor="rebeccapurple" nocolor="beige" color="goldenrod"></star-rating>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => console.log(evt.target.getAttribute("n")))

  customElements.define("star-rating", class extends HTMLElement {
    set rating( rate ) {
      if (!String(rate).includes("%")) rate = Number(rate) / this.stars * 100 + "%";
      this.querySelector("#rating").setAttribute("width", rate);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let { bgcolor, stars, nocolor, color, rating } = this.attributes;
      this.stars = ~~stars.value || 5;
      this.innerHTML = 
        `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${this.stars*100} 100" style="cursor:pointer;width:300px">`
      + `<rect width="100%" height="100" fill="${nocolor.value}"/>`
      + `<rect id="rating"  height="100" fill="${color.value}"  />`
        + Array(  this.stars     ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<path fill="${bgcolor.value}" d="M${ n*100 } 0h102v100h-102v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19 13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>`)
               .join("")
        + Array(  this.stars * 2 ).fill()
               .map((i, n) => `<rect x="${ n*50 }" n="${n}" opacity="0" width="50" height="100"`
                  + ` onclick="dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))" `
                  + ` onmouseover="this.closest('star-rating').rating = ${(n+1)/2}"/>`)
              .join("") 
      + "</svg>";

      this.rating = rating.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, this looks super cool... how do I implement the click ement on this?

Comment: ``<star-rating>`` is a regular DOM element add a click listener (or at any parent); the  ``new Event('click')`` always bubbles up the DOM.

Comment: thanks, not familiar at all with this code sorry I'm a bit lost

Comment: It took us all a bit more than 10 minutes to learn... I am into modern Web Components for over 3 years now, and still learning. Disect every example; this actually is a simple one, all it does is create SVG.

Comment: would you be able to help me please? when I mousehover looks like the active states removes.

Comment: Yes, mouseover changes the ``<rect id="rating">`` width